# SQL Select/Introduce adding new values after every 3 rows

Tags: mysql, database, calculated-columns

My requirement is I wanted to give new values to the column after every 3 items/rows in the table.
My DB table is like this.

```
A   B   C
----------
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
a3  b3  c3
a4  b4  c4
a5  b5  c5
a6  b6  c6
a7  b7  c7
```

I wanted to add new column as D with new value that changes every 3 rows to my view

```
A   B   C  D
------------
a1  b1  c1 d1
a2  b2  c2 d1
a3  b3  c3 d1
a4  b4  c4 d2
a5  b5  c5 d2
a6  b6  c6 d2
a7  b7  c7 d3
```

Is is possible with the SQL select statement?

Comment: Ya i think now it is possible to understand.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself first? If yes, please post that code as well.

Comment: Where you get the values d1, d2 and d3. Is it a random or sequential value. Post with sample data for a,b,c and d series

Comment: ya these values are sequential but hard coded values.